# C# - Read Nested Event Log From Custom Application

Tags: c#, .net, logging, analysis

I am using [sysmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348) to capture a bunch of event information (network connections, DLL loads, etc). I want to pull that information and use it for various purposes, but it doesn't seem like there is any way to retrieve the nested logs. They reside at

```
Event Viewer/Applications and Services/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational
```

All of the code I've tried only pulls the "standard" Event Logs. For example:

```
EventLog[] eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
```

has "Application", "Hardware Events", "Internet Explorer", etc.

I know how to create and retrieve custom event logs, but that doesn't seem to apply here, as these logs are not in the standard locations. Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I would try looking at the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader` namespace. It has a much richer API for getting event logs. `EventLogSession.GetLogNames` returns much larger list than `EventLog.GetEventLogs`.

Comment: ^^ This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you so much :) If you answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [`System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. In particular, you can get a complete list of log names from:

```
EventLogSession.GlobalSession.GetLogNames()
```

This has a much more complete list than `EventLog.GetEventLogs()`. Other useful classes in this namespace are `EventLogReader` and `EventLogWatcher`.