# Access nested event log in C#

Tags: c#, event-log

I am trying to get printer-related logs using `EventLog`.

I've enumerated all logs in system, using hint from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725103/c-sharp-read-nested-event-log-from-custom-application), like that:

```
foreach (var e in EventLogSession.GlobalSession.GetLogNames()) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

And I got log name of needed log - `Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational`.

However, this piece of code is crashing:

```
var evt = new EventLog("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational");
```

with

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The event log 'Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational' on computer '.' does not exist.
```

I am running MSVC 2015 under administrator.

```
new EventLog("Application");
```

is working like a charm, how I can create custom nested event log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only looking to read events you can try the `EventReader` class:

```
 var printerServiceQuery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational", PathType.LogName);
 var reader = new EventLogReader(printerServiceQuery);
 EventRecord entry = null;
 while( (entry = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(entry.FormatDescription());
 }
```